# How Do i Fix Light Scratches?

Tags: nintendo-switch

I have had my Nintendo Switch for a long time now, and it has gotten some scratches. Is there a way to fix these scratches without having to spend a lot of money on it? I have seen a few solutions such as toothpaste and nail polish remover, but I feel a bit nervous about them as they may damage my Nintendo Switch. Does anyone have any quick, cheap, and working solutions?

Comment: Are the scratches on the case or on the display? If it's on the case, you can just paint over it. If it's on the display, painting over it is probably not a good idea.

Comment: I think you're talking about the screen and the back of the Switch. If so, then I'd like to focus on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an answer to screen durability, I trust JerryRigEverything [to show us what's what](https://youtu.be/XJP6gERPmMk?t=48). Sadly, the Nintendo Switch's screen is made from **Plastic**, and is much more apt to scratching than a phone screen made of glass. Repairing scratched plastic is nigh impossible, and some of the methods you listed (toothpaste, nail polish remover) will likely do more harm than good.

If your device is under warranty, you may be in luck on getting the screen replaced, and it's worth reaching out to Nintento's customer support to confirm.

If you're feeling plucky, you can always attempt to replace the screen on your own, using [replacement parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07MX6X28G) and [a guide from a reputable source like iFixit.](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Nintendo+Switch+Screen+Replacement/140021) Otherwise, you may just need to bite the bullet, put a tempered glass screen protector on it to prevent further damage, and hope that your brain can ignore the scratch.

Comment: well legend has it that a new nintendo switch will be coming soon this year, i dont have the switch but i think the best choice is to just wait